# Don't want Navigation Bar links to change color when clicked (hover effect)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation, hover

When clicking on one of my navigations in my header, they change colors once they have been clicked. What is even more weird is the fact that my Home and Sign In button doesn't change but the rest do.

I want to know how to remove this effect because it darkens my text too much. (Let me be more specific: I don't want the gray coloring behind the words that you see behind the text)

My Html:

```
<h1 class = "name"><font color = "#3399FF"> Prog-Assist |  </font><font size = "12" font color = "#4EA24E"> Where Collaboration is Welcomed</font></h1>

<div id = "header">
    <div id = "gradient">
        <div class = "nav">

    <!-- container-fluid gives full width container of whole viewport -->

    <div class = "container-fluid">

    <ul id = "nav1" class= "text-left">
        <li><a href = "main.html"><strong>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "tech.html">Technologies</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Blog</strong></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id = "nav2" class = "text-right">
        <li><a href = "#"><strong>Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">Contact</strong></a></li>
    </ul>

    </div><!-- end container-fluid-->
        </div><!--end nav-->
    </div>
 </div> <!-- end header -->
```

My CSS:

```
h1.name{

/*font-family: Lato, 'Courier Bold', sanserif;*/
font-family: 'KOMIKAX_';
src: url(KOMIKAX_.tff);
font-weight: bold;
font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 60px;
color: "red";
margin-left: 30px;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;

}

#header {
margin-left: 30px;
width:cover;
}

#gradient {
    height: 65px;
border: 1px solid;
/* IE 10 */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #81a8cb 0%, #1947D1 100%);

/* Firefox */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #81a8cb, #1947D1); 

/* Safari  & Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top, color-stop(0, #1947D1),color-stop(1, #81a8cb)); 

box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px black;
}



#nav1 {

list-style: none;

}

#nav2 {

list-style: none;

}

.nav a {

text-decoration: none; /*remove underline*/
text-transform: uppercase;
color: white;
font-family: Rockwell, 'Courier Bold', serif;
font-size: 20px;
padding-bottom: 15px;

}

.nav li {

display: inline;
float: left;
padding: 10px;


}

.nav a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bolder;
}
.nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  #A7D1A7;

}
.nav a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #19A3FF;
    font-weight:bolder;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 .nav a:visited, .nav a:hover{background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
```

If this still does not work you may have some sort of other CSS overwriting it in the page then you would use the !important hack.

```
 .nav a:visited, .nav a:hover{background-color:transparent !important; text-decoration:none}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if there was a term to use to make the hover background color empty.. I will check mark this when I am allowed to (the timer said i have to wait)

Answer (score 1):

use css pseudo classes.

```
/* unvisited link */
header a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
header a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
header a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
header a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I mean the hover color effect. I will change title

Comment: the on hover effects can be set in the a:hover

Comment: Then how do i set the hover to "none"? My question is to remove it. My current code doesn't have any color effects for the background color

Comment: If you have already defined the look and feel of the element. Define the :hover effects to be same as what you have define for its regular look and feel. and you wont feel the difference on hover.

Answer (score 1):

css pseudo class :visited is to be used

```
a:visited{ text-decoration:none; color:#fff;}
```

Comment: the hover gray color still shows this way. I have a a:visited already but i don't have a "background-color" effect that shows in my image

Answer (score 1):

```
a:visited { 
  text-decoration:none; 
  color:#fff;
}
```